# .NET Core MediaElement Play Video With Alpha Channel

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core

How to play a video(mp4 file) which has alpha channel(trans parent back ground), in .NET Core, using `MediaElement` or `MediaPlayer`?

New to to `.NET Core`, `C#` programming, trying to play `MP4` file which has alpha channel(trans parent background), could not find a way.